# How to rename a GitHub wiki page?

Tags: github, wiki

On GitHub I created a wiki page, "Page1", but now I realize it was a bad name and I want to rename it to "Page2" instead.

There are many external third-party HTTP links to Page1, so deleting it would be bad for the users and for SEO.

Is there a way to redirect Page1 to Page2 like in Wikipedia?

(GitHub uses the Gollum wiki engine)

Answer (score 3):

I have not found any better solution than this so far:

1. Create Page2,
2. Copy-paste content of Page1 to Page2,
3. Replace content of Page1 with a link to Page2 like this: `Moved, please see [[Page 2]]`.

Answer (score 1):

### Solution with keeping the original page

It is not possible to create a "moved permanently" response. Besides the manual way, you can do following locally:

1. Clone the wiki repository (see URL at "Clone this wiki locally")
2. Copy `x.md` to `Y.md` (where X is the old page, Y the new page)
3. Replace the contents of `X.md` by a text and a link to `Y.md` (e.g. `Moved, please see [[Y]]`).
4. `git add -A`
5. `git commit -m "Rename X to Y and add a link from X to Y"`
6. `git push`

### Solution without keeping the original page

This is not good for SEO, but might be useful at the beginning of creation of a wiki.

You can clone the wiki repository (see URL at "Clone this wiki locally"), rename the file locally, do a `git add -A`, `git commit -m "Rename file"` and a `git push`.

Comment: You need to stage the new file.